# What percentage of rock guitarists didn't take lessons?

Tags: history, terminology

I'm wondering if guys like hendrix, frusciante, most punk rock guitar/solo.. were able to understand music theory ?

Comment: Hello and welcome! At the moment your title looks like you are looking for a list - that may mean your question gets closed as list questions are discouraged here. If you wanted to ask e.g. "What percentage of rock guitarists didn't take lessons", I personally would see that as a good question (though others may disagree). There's a question about Hendrix already : http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/946/is-it-true-that-jimi-hendrix-didnt-know-music-theory

Comment: HI @topomorto i really liked your suggestion you're right, i'll edit my title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my very rough impression rather than a formal survey, but from reading a lot of interviews and biographies over the years, I get the idea that around a third of prominent guitarists had a significant amount of formal tuition, around a third learned mostly 'by ear', and then the remaining third are somewhere in the middle (perhaps having been in a situation where they could learn non-formally from people around them).

As for 'knowing theory' - well, theory can be seen as a mixture of

- some fundamental rules about how music works
- some terminology and definitions that can be useful when communicating with others
- some guidelines and ideas that are specific to certain musical styles

You could take the view that if you had a good musical ear, [you would actually figure out a lot of the fundamental stuff for yourself anyway](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/958/16). Use of a particular set of terminology may not matter to you if you can find another way to communicate your ideas (after all, terminology doesn't affect how the music *sounds*), and if you're only interested in playing your own style, you might not need to learn a lot about how to play and write in other styles.

Ultimately it shouldn't be a surprise that a lot of prominent guitarists haven't studied a lot of theory, as [the field of music theory doesn't (yet) really get to the bottom of how music makes us feel the way we do](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/43108/18896) - so we are all 'figuring it out by ear' to some extent, even those of us who know a lot of theory.

From a practical point of view, the standard way of naming notes (letters A to G, sharps and flats, etc.) is somewhat easier to apply directly to the piano than the guitar, due to the way the piano is laid out.

As a side note, it's worth noting that a much higher percentage of session musicians have studied formally, as the communication and style skills that formal study can teach are more useful in that situation.